# How to reformat active boot drive

Tags: boot, ssd

Raspberry Pi 4B 8gb

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

My Raspberry Pi boots full blown Ubuntu from my 1tb SSD. I want to change the OS on the SSD from Ubuntu to Lubuntu (I'm not concerned with the contents of the SSD). I'm trying to boot from my original Ubuntu bootable Micro SD card so that I can format and re-image the SSD with Lubuntu **but the RPi always boots from the SSD**.

So to be clear, my goal is to re-image my current bootable SSD with Lubuntu.

1. How do I format the SSD when the SSD is the active boot drive?

OR

2. How do I boot from the Micro SD card **and not** from the SSD so that I can reformat the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

raspberrypi.stackexchange.com might give you better answers but,

Typically you can change the boot target of a raspberry pi using the config.txt file found in the boot partition of the sd-card.

From there, for booting, target a USB drive (I'm assuming) with the Lubuntu installer image on it, and just overwrite everything on the SSD. Once installed, reset the config.txt to boot from the SSD and you should be good to go. This kind-of thing is explained pretty well (maybe too verbose) in the raspberry pi documentation:

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes

Alternatively, I'm not exactly sure if this will work, but you might see what happens if you boot the raspberry pi with the SSD detached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As it turns out, I had to unplug the ssd from the RPi and boot with the micro sd os. Then I plugged the ssd card into the usb and Ubuntu let me format it.